# WP_Query - show posts where meta value and user_email match

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I have a post type "contracts" and on a specific page template want to show posts where the meta_key "distributor_email" matches the current user's email. Have tried both of the following and both return a 500 internal server error. Which probably means I'm missing something pretty basic but I haven't been able to figure it out and I would really appreciate another set of eyeballs on this.

```
            <?php
            $userEmail;
            if ( wp_get_current_user() instanceof WP_User ) {
                    $userEmail = wp_get_current_user()->user_email;
            }
            $users_query = new WP_Query( array(
                    'post_type' => 'contracts',
                    'meta_key' => 'distributor_email',
                    'meta_value' => $userEmail,
            ) ); ?>

<?php if ( $users_query->have_posts() ): ?>

                <?php while ( $users_query->have_posts(): $users_query->the_post() ) ?>
                <div class="loginContract">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="pink"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        <?php the_content(); ?> 
                </div>      
                <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

And this is the second one I tried..

```
            <?php
            $userEmail;
            if ( wp_get_current_user() instanceof WP_User ) {
                    $userEmail = wp_get_current_user()->user_email;
            }
            $users_query = new WP_Query( array(
                    'post_type' => 'contracts',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'key'     => 'distributor_email',
                            'value'   => $userEmail,
                            'compare' => '=',
                        ),
                    ),

            ) );


        ?>
<?php if ( $users_query->have_posts() ): ?>

                <?php while ( $users_query->have_posts(): $users_query->the_post() ) ?>
                <div class="loginContract">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="pink"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        <?php the_content(); ?> 
                </div>      
                <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: I expect the first line would throw a syntax error. Have you enabled debugging? Then you'll get error messages telling you which line the problem is in.

Answer (score 0):

Both examples of your code throw errors on the `while` line:

```
<?php while ( $users_query->have_posts(): $users_query->the_post() ) ?>
```

The `while` will work if you move the parenthesis from the end to before the colon, and replace the parenthesis with a semicolon.

```
<?php while ( $users_query->have_posts() ) : $users_query->the_post() ; ?>
```

(The Errors turn up fast on WP PHP Console: Don't stay home without it... I've gotten into the habit of testing this stuff out using it with Shortcode Exec PHP.)